# Database is created ! But the table gets no values

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

A simple registration page where username, password, and confirm password these three textfields. I am going to create a database having a table of three attributes id, name, and password where id is primary key, name we get from username textfield dynamically and password we get from password textfield dynamically.But, the problem is that Database is created but the values given dynamically do not get stored/updated in the table. I am a novice in android, and I have used internet resources to write the code but still i am getting no clue in this stage. Thanks in advance..!!

```
MainActivity.java :
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword;
Button btnCreateAccount;
DbHelper myHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);

    myHelper = new DbHelper(this, "", null, 1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    public void newName(View v) {
        // onClick function when account create button is clicked

        String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        Bus bus = new Bus(userName, password);
        myHelper.insertEntry(bus);
        String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
               bus = new Bus(userName, password);
               myHelper.insertEntry(bus);
               editTextUserName.setText("");
               editTextPassword.setText("");
               editTextConfirmPassword.setText("");

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

        public void count (View view) {
//onClick function when no of tuples in the table button is clicked

            int a = myHelper.getNamesCount();
            String b = Integer.toString(a);
            editTextUserName.setText(b);

       }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    myHelper.close();
}
}
```

and there is another database helper class called DbHelper.java, code is :

```
DbHelper.java :
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "finalProjectDB.db";
private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "Table1";

public static final String COLUMN_ID1 = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME1 = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD1 = "password";

public DbHelper(Context context, String name, 
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public  SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      String CREATE_NAMES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_LOGIN+"("+COLUMN_ID1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+COLUMN_NAME1+" TEXT,"+COLUMN_PASSWORD1+" TEXT)";
      db.execSQL(CREATE_NAMES_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_LOGIN);
      onCreate(db);
}



public void insertEntry(Bus bus)
{
   ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

    newValues.put("COLUMN_NAME1",bus.getName());
    newValues.put("COLUMN_PASSWORD1",bus.getPassword());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.insert("TABLE_LOGIN", null, newValues);
    ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();


}

public int getNamesCount(){

    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM "+TABLE_LOGIN;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    return count;
}

}
```

Finally, Bus.java file :

```
Bus.java :
public class Bus {
private int _id;
    private String _name;
    private String _password;

    public Bus(){

    }

    public Bus(int id, String name, String password){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._password = password;
    }

    public Bus(String name, String password){
        this._name = name;
        this._password = password;
    }

    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this._name;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this._password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this._password;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have an error in your code :

```
db.insert("TABLE_LOGIN", null, newValues);
```

So you try to insert values in a table that does not exist.

Use your constant instead of a String.